# Stop HtmlUnit download after specified file size is reached

Tags: java, inputstream, htmlunit

I'm stuck trying to stop a download initiated with HtmlUnit after a certain size was reached. The InputStream

```java
InputStream input = button.click().getWebResponse().getContentAsStream();
```

downloads the complete file correctly. However, seems like using

```java
OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
int bytesRead;
int total = 0;
while ((bytesRead = input.read(buffer)) != -1 && total < MAX_SIZE) {
  output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
  total += bytesRead;
  System.out.print(total + "\n");
}
output.flush();
output.close();
input.close();
```

somehow downloads the file to a different location (unknown to me) and once finished copies the max size into the file "fileName". No System.out is printed during this process. Interestingly, while running the debugger in Netbeans and going slowly step-by-step, the total is printed and I get the MAX_SIZE file.

Varying the buffer size in a range between 1024 to 102400 didn't make any difference.

I also tried Commons'

```java
BoundedInputStream b = new BoundedInputStream(button.click().getWebResponse().getContentAsStream(), MAX_SIZE);
```

without success.

There's [this 2,5 years old post](http://htmlunit.10904.n7.nabble.com/A-question-on-downloading-file-via-HtmlUnit-tp23300p23302.html), but I couldn't figure out how to implement the proposed solution.

Is there something I'm missing in order to stop the download at MAX_SIZE?

(Exceptions handling and other etcetera omitted for brevity)

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use HTMLUnit for this. Actually, using it to such a simple task is a very overkill solution and will make things slow. The best approach I can think of is the following:

```
final String url = "http://yoururl.com";
final String file = "/path/to/your/outputfile.zip";
final int MAX_BYTES = 1024 * 1024 * 5;  // 5 MB

URLConnection connection = new URL(url).openConnection();
InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
int pendingRead = MAX_BYTES;
int n;
OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(new File(file));
while ((n = input.read(buffer)) >= 0 && (pendingRead > 0)) {
    output.write(buffer, 0, Math.min(pendingRead, n));
    pendingRead -= n;
}
input.close();
output.close();
```

In this case I've set a maximum download size of 5 MB and a buffer of 4 KB. The file will be written to disk in every iteration of the `while` loop, which seems to be what you're looking for.

Of course, make sure you handle all the needed exceptions (eg: `FileNotFoundException`).

Comment: Thanks. I included HtmlUnit because first I need to click a button, which sends a POST request and then redirects me to the actual download. As I have some experience with HtmlUnit, I didn't really search for a solution without it. I'll give it a try and report back.

Comment: Can you post the whole solution in which you set the file to download as well as the limit that it should have? Regarding, the second comment which I think it refers to limiting the download size in HTMLUnit itself, the short answer is *No, you can't*. The long answer is: *It is open source, so you can extend HTMLUnit the way you can. You can attach your custom made [`HttpWebConnection`](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/HttpWebConnection.html) to a WebClient and perform request from there... making sure that not ALL requests get cut, right?*

Comment: HttpClient did the trick. The client is build as `CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().setRedirectStrategy(new LaxRedirectStrategy()).build();` in order to be closable at will and to handle the redirection after the POST. The I/O routine remains the same, but closing the CloseableHttpResponse and then the InputStream. @Mosty: I'll try that too, I'd like to keep HtmlUnit in my project, makes all the complementary clicking much easier.